# How to fix Totem's "Invalid Commandline" error?

Tags: gnome, totem

Whenever I attempt to play a video (or an audio file) with Totem I get the following error:

```
totem invalid commandline The parameters passed to the application had an invalid format. Please file a bug!
The parameters were: --transient-for=75497483 gstreamer|1.0|totem|H.264 decoder|decoder-video/x-h264, level=(string)3, profile=(string)high, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, parsed=(boolean)true
```

I've added the gnome3 team's PPA if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem as you did. So I tested my video playback (mp4, h264) with VLC and it worked very well. But I wasn't able to have Quicktime playback in Firefox with the `mozilla-plugin-vlc` and `browser-plugin-vlc`.

So my advise to you would be to use `mplayer` with `gecko-mediaplayer`. This solves all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

This solve my problem.

```
sudo apt-get install h264enc
```

will install H.264 in your system.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for awhile on debian. The solution was to install some recommended packages of totem. `gstreamer1.0-libav` helped there.